# monotouch scripting for ios(ipad/iphone)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog, xamarin.mac

How can we make any column as a hyperlink/tapable in `GridView` table using monotouch scripting.
Suppose I have a table of 5 columns and 6 rows. I want to make 4th column records(data) as a hyperlink, i.e all 6 rows of 4th column should be hyperlink and tapable.

Comment: By coding, what have you tried?

Comment: iOS doesn't have a GridView control.

Comment: @Lakshan-I am beginner in this. I tried with new UIlabel() and make it as hyperlnk using css. By this its creating new label and making that new label as hyperlink but not to the actual data of table. In column same value is displaying twice.

Comment: @Jason-I agree. Its similar kind of grid. I am geting the control of table using getControl()